# Can't display the proper value

Tags: java, arrays

I have these classes:

```
interface Shape
{
    public double getPerimeter();
    public double getArea();
    public void getDetails(); 
}
```

and

```
class Circle implements Shape
{
    private double PI = 3.14;
    private int radius;
    double perimeter, area;

    //constructor
    public Circle(int radius)
    {
        perimeter = 2.0 * (PI * radius);
        area = PI * (radius * radius);
    }

    public int getRadius()
    {
        return radius;
    }

    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        return perimeter;
    }

    public double getArea()
    {
        return area;
    }

    public void getDetails()
    {
        System.out.println("Shape Type: Circle " + "\n"
                         + "Radius: " + getRadius() + "\n"                          
                         + "Perimeter: " + getPerimeter() + "\n"    
                         + "Area: "  + getArea() + "\n"         );
    }
}
```

and finally

```
public class TestShape
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            }

            catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
                System.err.print("wrong");
            }

            catch(IllegalArgumentException iae)
            {
                System.err.print("wrong");
            }

            if(args.length==1)
            {
                i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                Circle r1 = new Circle(i);
                r1.getDetails();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

We were assigned to input 1,2 or 3 numbers on the command line of the terminal and the output would display what kind of shape it is depending on the array size. I managed to get the proper parameter and area when I input a number but the radius keeps displaying 0 instead of the actual number I inputted.

[This is what the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aUO3.png)

So what do you guys think?

Comment: Is this Java? It looks like Java. Please remember the correct language tag next time. Also please try to refrain from profanity. And don't post (links to) images containing text. Copy-paste the text *as* text* into the question body instead. And *what is your question?* What is the problem you have with the code you show? Please take some time to  [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Neat error handling messages...

Comment: This is a simple missing line, I have voted to closed as a typo an not necessary in for the futur of SO.

Comment: I'm sorry about the unnecessary profanity I forgot to edit them out

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the radius in the constructor of Circle...

```
public Circle(int radius)
{
    perimeter = 2.0 * (PI * radius);
    area = PI * (radius * radius);
    this.radius = radius // this statement is missing
}
```

Therefore, `circle.getRadius()` always returns the uninitialized default int value `0`.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor:

```
public Circle(int radius)
{
    perimeter = 2.0 * (PI * radius);
    area = PI * (radius * radius);
}
```

`radius` refers to the parameter `radius`, not the `radius` field declared in `Circle`. You need to make them the same by assigning the `radius` parameter to the `radius` field. To refer to the `radius` *field*, use `this.radius`.

```
this.radius = radius;
```

Because you did not do this in your code, the `radius` returned by `getRadius` is 0, which is the default value of an unassigned `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Instance variable are assigned values by default if not initialized. In case of int it's 0 by default. So to assign the value to your instance variable radius you need to add this line in your constructor.

> this.radius = radius

We are using **this** because your instance variable and local variable are having the same name.